# What's the simplest way to make a local address socket publicly available?

Tags: sockets, http, networking

I have a HTTP enabled device on my local network that listens at let's say *192.168.1.32:9427*. What's the simplest way to make public access to that socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to port forward from public ip address to private ip-address on `port no. 9427`

example:

public ip : `20.20.20.20` 
private ip : `192.168.1.32`
Now when someone try to access your local http server should access via `20.20.20.20:9427`

to do that :

1. you need to enable that on your adsl modem or on your router device 
   to do that for your adsl modem from here
   [How to Port Forward Your Router](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/)
2. check open ports to see if `port no. 9427` is opened or not

   [Open Port Check Tool](http://www.canyouseeme.org/)
3. you need to allow your iptables if you are using linux machine and allow port no. 9427
   to do that :

   `iptables -I INPUT 1 -p --dport 9427 -s -j ACCEPT`
4. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`